# How do I insert a Swedish characters into a NVARCHAR2 Oracle table column type?

Tags: oracle

I insert it like this:

```
insert into s_test values('Länsförsäkringar');
```

Getting back this:

```
select * from s_test;

L�nsf�rs�kringar
```

Here � is a replacement char \003F

Expectation:

```
select * from s_test;

Länsförsäkringar
```

Relevant NLS params:

```
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
NLS_CHARACTERSET    US7ASCII
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_RDBMS_VERSION   11.2.0.3.0
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE "S_TEST" 
   (    "COL1" NVARCHAR2(100) ) ;
```

How do I insert Swedish characgers into Oracle NVARCHAR2 column type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `N`:

```
insert into s_test values(N'Länsförsäkringar');
```

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218

> The syntax of text literals or strings follows:
>
> [image]
>
> where N or n specifies the literal using the national character set
> (NCHAR or NVARCHAR2 data). By default, text entered using this
> notation is translated into the national character set by way of the
> database character set when used by the server. To avoid potential
> loss of data during the text literal conversion to the database
> character set, set the environment variable ORA_NCHAR_LITERAL_REPLACE
> to TRUE. Doing so transparently replaces the n' internally and
> preserves the text literal for SQL processing.

Comment: thank you, that worked in SQL*Plus, but  in Java 1.4/JDBC prepared statement it fails..

Comment: In java use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), it's [setString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString(int,%20java.lang.String)) method automatically converts unicode java strings to NVarchar

Comment: in JDK 1.4 with Weblogic JDBC i get replacement chars \003F.

Comment: in 1.6 i can do :pstmt.setFormOfUse(1, oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement.FORM_NCHAR);    but not in 1.4