# How to create table with column names and Entries with Unicode Character in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, unicode, nvarchar

I've tried following queries,

```
create table विद्यार्थी(आयडी int, नाव varchar(50), वर्ग varchar(10));
insert into विद्यार्थी values(1,'अक्षय','पहिली'); 
insert into विद्यार्थी values(2,'नारायण','दुसरी');
```

This works well in MySQL but it doesn't work in Oracle.
Oracle Gives Error as `Invalid Character`

---

Then I tried to use column names in English as follows with datatype NVARCHAR2.

```
create table student(id int, name nvarchar2(50), class nvarchar2(50));
insert into student values(1,'अक्षय','पहिली'); 
insert into student values(2,'नारायण','दुसरी');
```

No Error, but when I fire

```
select * from student;
```

After firing SELECT query, I got values from Table as inverted question marks as shown in screenshot attached. Oracle 10g and Oracle 12c, both give same result.

[image: Unicode Representation by Oracle 10g]

1. So How can I use column names with unicode characters in Oracle?
2. If I used English column names with datatype NVARCHAR2 and inserted unicode character values, then why I'm not getting unicode character values in result of SELECT query as show in screenshot? How to sort out this?

Comment: What do you get by `SELECT * 
    FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS 
    WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';`?

Comment: Parameter : NLS_CHARACTERSET
Value : WE8MSWIN1252

Comment: The the answer is simple: Is is not possible. Migrate your database to Unicode, i.e. character set `AL32UTF8`

Comment: I am not at all familiar with Oracle, so forgive me if I have it wrong, but 1) isn't the NVARCHAR2 type encoded in UTF-16, no matter the NLS_CHARACTERSET? And 2) when inserting into a NCHARCHAR field, you should use the N notation. `insert into student values(1, N'अक्षय', N'पहिली');` See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/42167363/1016716

Comment: Usually `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` is UTF-16. However, table and column names are stored as `VARCHAR2`, not `NVARCHAR2` (see Datatype at [ALL_TAB_COLUMNS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm))

Comment: How can I set characterset to AL32UTF8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle this should be possible:

```
create table "विद्यार्थी" ("आयडी" integer, "नाव" varchar(50), "वर्ग" varchar(10));
```

However, I would recommend "standard" characters and then use a view with devanagari:

```
create table MY_TABLE(ID integer, NAME varchar(50), CLASS varchar(10));

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "विद्यार्थी" AS
SELECT ID AS "आयडी", NAME AS "नाव", CLASS AS "वर्ग";
```

NB, you could also insert data into the view with `insert into "विद्यार्थी" values (1,'अक्षय','पहिली');`

Do you have any other SQL client, e.g. TOAD or SQL Developer rather than APEX in internet explorer? Character encoding could be a challenge there.

Comment: `create table "विद्यार्थी" ("आयडी" integer, "नाव" varchar(50), "वर्ग" varchar(10));`
--> Error : ORA-00957: duplicate column name

Comment: _Do you have any other SQL client, e.g. TOAD or SQL Developer rather than APEX in internet explorer? Character encoding could be a challenge there._
 
**I've tried same thing on Mozilla Firefox and SQL Developer that comes with Oracle 12c, but still it fails to represent Devanagari characters**

Comment: MS Internet Explorer or Firefox does not really make any difference.

Comment: _Does it work with the View?_ 
`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "विद्यार्थी" AS SELECT ID AS "आयडी", NAME AS "नाव", CLASS AS "वर्ग" from STUDENT;`

Same Error : **ORA-00957: duplicate column name**

Comment: Idea of View to make Table and Column names with Devanagari characters doesn't work. Giving Error : **ORA-00957: duplicate column name **. 

Instead of Browsers, I tried SQL Developer that comes with Oracle 12c. It does not work too.

Comment: Most likely this is caused by the character encoding, i.e. the command is translated to `create table "?????" ("?????" integer, "????" varchar(50), "????" varchar(10));` - then the error is obvious.

Comment: So what's solution?

Comment: In case of representation of result of select Query, browsers and SQL Developer fails. But in JAVA, if I set appropriate devanagari fonts for Label and Textboxes and fetch values from Database then Textboxes and Labels from java represent Devanagari letters as expected even though I'm getting ???? result of select query fired from Browser and SQL Developer !

Comment: That means Devanagari letters are stored in Database at backend but browsers and SQL Developers are not able to represent it properly. Hence giving result like Inverted Question marks. Adjusting default font of SQL Developer and Browsers does not work !

Comment: No, when the character set is `WE8MSWIN1252` then Devanagari cannot be stored in database (as `VARCHAR2` datatype) and the browser or any other client cannot represent them either.

Comment: So how can I change it?

Comment: Oracle 12c allow us to select character set while creating database, but in case of Oracle 10g, usually we deal with default Database scheme XE. 

How can I change characterset to AL32UTF8 in Oracle 10g?

Comment: Oracle 10g is 15 years old! Consider an upgrade to a supported version.

Comment: Oracle 10g takes less time for installing. I want to install it on end-users machine. Updated version of Oracle takes lot of time for installing.

Comment: Oracle 10g ( 157 MB ), Oracle 12c ( 2.5 GB ), Oracle 18c ( 4.4 GB ). Oracle 10g fulfill the requirements of my project for English Language. I'm getting problem with Devanagari characters only.

Comment: Everything worked with Oracle 11g Express Edition. It sizes about 317 MB only. Thank you very much !